# Update parent object when child objects meet certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models - Order and Item:

order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
end
```

schema for item:

```
t.decimal  "price",       precision: 12, scale: 3
t.string   "status"
```

schema for order:

```
 t.string   "status"
```

Item's status will be marked as shipped when user received the items. So how can I update my order status to "complete",  in the condition that all items' status are updated to "shipped"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `items` table to include a [`foreign key`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), relating it to `orders`:

```
$ rails g new migration AddOrderIDToItems

#db/migrate/add_order_id_to_items______.rb
class AddOrderIdToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
      add_column :items, :order_id, :integer
   end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

You can read more about why this is important [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

[image]

-

This will allow you to do the following:

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items, inverse_of: :order
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :order, inverse_of: :items
   after_save :check_order, on: :update

   private

   def check_order
      items = Item.where(order_id: order.id).where.not(status: "shipped").count
      order.update(status: "complete") if items > 0
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
@item = Item.find params[:id]
@item.update(status: "shipped") #-> "check_order" will happen, saving "order" as "complete" if all items are shipped
```

---

The real fix for this is to create a `has_many :through` relationship, to associate many `Items` to many `Orders`. This way, you can mark each of the `OrderItems` as "shipped":

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :order_items
   has_many :items, through: :order_items
end

#app/models/order_item.rb
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | order_id | item_id | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :order
   belongs_to :item

   after_save :check_order, on: :update

   private

   def check_order
      items = Item.where(order_id: order.id).where.not(status: "shipped").count
      order.update(status: "complete") if items > 0
   end
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :order_items
   has_many :orders, through: :order_items
end
```

You only need to introduce the `OrderItem` model (changes to `Item` and `Order` models are not necessary):

[image]

This will allow you to do the following:

```
@order = Order.find params[:id]
@item = Item.find params[:id]

@order.items << @item #-> adds "item" to order
```

You'll then be able to use the following to set whether the order has been "completed" or not:

```
@order = Order.find params[:id]

@item = @order.order_items.find x
@item.update status: "shipped"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def complete_order
     order.complete if all_items_shipped?
  end

  def shipped?
    status == 'shipped'
  end

  private

  def all_items_shipped?
    order.items.all?(&:shipped?)
  end
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def complete
    update status: 'complete'
  end
end
```

And then call `item.complete_order` everytime a `Item` is marked as `shipped`.

Comment: Where should I call `item.complete_order` or should I use callbacks like after_update? And what if I got another condition that item's status = "refund", so if 2 items are "shipped" and 1 item is "refund", order's status should mark as "incomplete". Thanks.

Comment: You said: *Item's status will be marked as shipped when user received the items*, so you call `item.complete_order` in the same moment / place where item status is updated. For the second question, I'd add it to the question's body, since it's actually another feature. You'd replicate the logic to handle that case, in a similar way.